# Call method from aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an asp.net mvc 2 project. In my controller I have the following method:

```
public string getTimeZone(double lat, double lon)
    {
        return (lat+lon).ToString();
    }
```

I'd like to display that result in my aspx page, to somehow call the method:

```
 <%# getTimeZone(Model.Lat, Model.Lon) %>
```

How can I do that?

Comment: You can't. Store it in the ViewData or better yet.. your actual model.

Answer (score -2):

You're close. It's

```
<%= getTimeZone(Model.Lat, Model.Lon) %>
```

Comment: This way I get the following error: the name getTimeZone doesn't exist in the following context. However, the method is defined in the controller.